# Form labels + data is not centering correctly

Tags: html, css, forms, center

Please log into my website using:

username: test
password: test

and then go to http://www.budgie.richardcmpage.com/profile.php

I'm trying to get the profile info (only the top part, ignore the bottom forms) in the centre of the page but it's not quite right.

```
    <div id="profile_bg">

    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <div class="middle">
    <ul class="headers">        
        <li>Username: <span class="output_username"> <?php echo $username ?></span> </li>
        <li>Full Name: <span class="output_fullname"><?php echo $fullname ?></span> </li>
        <li>Email Address: <span class="output_email"><?php echo $email ?></span> </li>
        <li>Location: <span class="output_location"><?php echo $location ?></span> </li>
        <li>Country: <span class="output_country"><?php echo $country ?></span>  </li>
    </ul> 
     </div>
</div>

CSS


#profile_bg{
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:#42592C;
    font-size:13px;     
}

    .middle{
    display:block;  
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:280px;
    height:110px;
}

    .headers {  
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:10px;        
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The black box of the profile information appears in the center of the lighter green box.

Comment: I only put the black box to try something out. I just want the block of text, when I say block I mean the Username: asdasd, email: asdsad ETC to be in the center of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but it will center it.

```
.headers {  
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;   
}
```

Comment: I only put the black box to try something out. I just want the block of text, when I say block I mean the Username: asdasd, email: asdsad ETC to be in the center of the page. 

Yeah I don't want the text to be centered as such.

Comment: Add a border to "middle", you'll see that it is positioned correctly.

Comment: I think it looks offcenter, if you see the | in the navbar, it needs to be more inline with that don't you think?

Comment: Just add some margin-left or margin-right you balance it out a but.